# S1000D JavaScript search engine

Tags: search-engines, javascript, jquery, data-storage

I am developping a static web application. My goal is to create a search engine.

So, I have a list of training's documents and I want to search a fulltext from each one;

My documents are stored on my disk in the norm [S1000D](http://public.s1000d.org/Pages/Home.aspx).

I want show DM-code for each founded fulltext.

Does exists this type of engine?

Comment: I have HTML+Jquery. that's it all my application
My question: is it possible to create a search engine with Jquery+html?

Comment: that will find a fulltext in collection of S1000D files

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean. Are you talking about offline search, or querying a server ?

If you have a server, you're probably good to go with a SOLR server + querying it with jQuery.ajax calls.

If you're looking for an offline solution, you can either do iterative regex lookups or use something along the lines of fullproof http://reyesr.github.com/fullproof/

Comment: yes, it s an offline solution that I want. I already have server version with SOLR. but not offline